# Show convergence by using partial fractions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, partial-fractions

Show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}}=\frac{1}{4}$

Answer:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}}=$ $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2(n+2)})}$

= $1/2 -1/2 + 1/6 +1/4 -1/3 +1/8+1/6 -1/4 +1/10 +1/8 -1/5 +1/12 +....$

How do I proceed further? Can anyone give hints/guide?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it telescope?

Comment: Yes, it does, but I can't seem to figure out the general pattern of the telescoping that's happening

Comment: basically, all the terms cancel out except for that first 1/4 that we have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can rewrite the sum as
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}\left( \left[ \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right] + \left[ \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \right] \right) $$
From this the way the sum telescopes should be clear.

Comment: Welcome to math.se!

Comment: Thank you! then the only term that is left is the 1/2 (1-1/2), if I'm not wrong? and all else cancel out

Comment: Yep, using this $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k + 2} - \frac{1}{2})$ which will converge to $\frac{1}{4}$ as $k \to \infty$

Comment: $ \frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k + 2} - \frac{1}{2})$ is the $k^{th}$ term of the sequence of partial sums of the series?

Comment: Yes, that is correct